# DataSet.GetXml() converts empty table cell to tag with attribute xml:space="preserve" and a space for value

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a problem with DataSet.GetXml() in ASP.NET 4.0:
First I populate the dataset with some tables.
Then I run the .GetXml() method on the dataset and some XML is returned. The output of this method is not want I want it to be, however.

The desired result is this:

```
<articles>
    <pkid>57456</pkid>
    <articleid>u34dh</articleid>
    <category>geysdfwty</category>
    <changed>1</changed>
    <email>asd@hwsfn.com</email>
    <header1>Gagasdy</header1>
    <intro>yhsghsdfhert ert erty</intro>
    <layout>Ajr66id</layout>
    <sectionid>jefgd</sectionid>
    <sortorder>0</sortorder>
    <passwordprotect>false</passwordprotect>
    <usr_postalcode>3745</usr_postalcode>
    <retailersort>Gadierg</retailersort>
    <enddate>08-06-2050 00:00:00</enddate>
    <startdate>08-03-2008 00:00:00</startdate>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <pkid>7845</pkid>
    <articleid>jkfgd</articleid>
    <category>Agjkeydfg</category>
    <changed>1</changed>
    <email>rt@jrudfbdn.com</email>
    <header1>GHadfghf</header1>
    <intro>Ahkrdfg ed tiedfh</intro>
    <layout>Ahoynf</layout>
    <sectionid>jkerbc</sectionid>
    <sortorder>0</sortorder>
    <passwordprotect>false</passwordprotect>
    <usr_postalcode>5484</usr_postalcode>
    <retailersort>Ajrtgdfg</retailersort>
    <enddate>08-06-2050 00:00:00</enddate>
    <startdate>08-03-2008 00:00:00</startdate>
  </articles>
```

The actual output is this:

```
<articles>
    <pkid>57456</pkid>
    <articleid>u34dh</articleid>
    <category>geysdfwty</category>
    <changed>1</changed>
    <email>asd@hwsfn.com</email>
    <factsbox xml:space="preserve"> </factsbox>
    <header1>Gagasdy</header1>
    <intro>yhsghsdfhert ert erty</intro>
    <keywords xml:space="preserve"> </keywords>
    <layout>Ajr66id</layout>
    <pagetext xml:space="preserve"> </pagetext>
    <sectionid>jefgd</sectionid>
    <sortorder>0</sortorder>
    <textbody xml:space="preserve"> </textbody>
    <passwordprotect>false</passwordprotect>
    <usr_postalcode>3745</usr_postalcode>
    <retailersort>Gadierg</retailersort>
    <enddate>08-06-2050 00:00:00</enddate>
    <startdate>08-03-2008 00:00:00</startdate>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <pkid>7845</pkid>
    <articleid>jkfgd</articleid>
    <category>Agjkeydfg</category>
    <changed>1</changed>
    <email>rt@jrudfbdn.com</email>
    <factsbox xml:space="preserve"> </factsbox>
    <header1>GHadfghf</header1>
    <intro>Ahkrdfg ed tiedfh</intro>
    <keywords xml:space="preserve"> </keywords>
    <layout>Ahoynf</layout>
    <pagetext xml:space="preserve"> </pagetext>
    <sectionid>jkerbc</sectionid>
    <sortorder>0</sortorder>
    <textbody xml:space="preserve"> </textbody>
    <passwordprotect>false</passwordprotect>
    <usr_postalcode>5484</usr_postalcode>
    <retailersort>Ajrtgdfg</retailersort>
    <enddate>08-06-2050 00:00:00</enddate>
    <startdate>08-03-2008 00:00:00</startdate>
  </articles>
```

In short, I also get cells that are empty in the dataset's table and the xml node of these cells get a xml:space="preserve" added.
How do I stop this from happening? I mean, how do I stop the cell from being included at all?

In ASP.NET 1.1 the same code is used and the desired output is returned. This means that it is probably some new thing in 4.0 that I have to switch on/off. But what?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out how to do this properly, so for now I just apply a RegEx to remove any empty tags that have the xml:space="preserve" attribute:

```
Dim reSpaceReplacer As New Regex("<[^ ]+ xml:space=""preserve"">\s+</[^>]+>")
strOutput = reSpaceReplacer.Replace(strOutput, "")
```